# Exception throws while Run the flutter plugin

Tags: flutter

> Improperly formatted define flag: memory
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'C:\newfluttersdk\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle'
>   line: 896
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
> > Process 'command 'C:\newfluttersdk\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         3.3s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

flutter doctor -v

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.18362.657], locale en-IN)
> • Flutter version 1.20.1 at C:\newfluttersdk\flutter
> • Framework revision 2ae34518b8 (5 days ago), 2020-08-05 19:53:19 -0700
> • Engine revision c8e3b94853
> • Dart version 2.9.0
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 29.0.3)
> • Android SDK at C:\Users\DeepikaRavi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
> • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
> • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
> • Dart plugin version 193.7361
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
>
> [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.45.0)
> • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
> • Flutter extension version 3.11.0
>
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
> • vivo Y51L (mobile) • 34d9bc20 • android-arm64 • Android 5.0.2 (API 21)
>
> • No issues found!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

@deepika can you please try this commands

````dart
flutter upgrade --force
flutter pub cache repair
cd <YOUR APP FOLDER>
flutter clean```
````

Comment: if still, the problem is there then please share the `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: The problem is there after try this commands and I shared the flutter doctor -v

Comment: then please follow this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56260 @Deepika

Comment: Thank you,I solved the issue by reinstalled my flutter SDK.

Comment: hey @Deepika can you please accept the answer if it is useful to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade version android.

like that

android/build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
```

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

delete you yamillock file and run get pub it solve the issue for me